# Differentiator circuit sees noise on PCB after 2 min

Tags: pcb-design, noise, differential

I'm new to PCB design, and looking for some advice. I designed a PCB shield and I'm seeing a lot of noise in my differentiator circuit. The circuit will run perfectly for about 2 min and then all of the sudden, a bunch of noise will disrupt the reading.
[image: Noise introduction]

The circuit itself works just fine as tested on a breadboard, but not when its on the PCB. Not sure if this helps, but I've attached an image of the Board schematic as well.

[image]

I'm worried about crosstalking and temperature issues with temperature. I'm not sure if this is a common issue and I'd love some advice. Thanks.

EDIT1: Added schematic. The bandwidth I'm looking for is below 1 kHz. The power input is the 3.3 V supply and GND pins connected to my microcontroller (TIVA TM4C123GXL).
[image]

Comment: Need a schematic also, what bandwidth do you need for your ADC readings? I don't see any bypass caps on that LTC1922, and the parasitic values on the traces will be quite high. Plus it looks like the supplies are being daisy chained, need to see what kind of power supplies you have.

Comment: I added a schematic above. The power input comes from the 3.3 V and GND pins of my microcontroller. As far as the bypass caps, they would go from outputs PD2/PD3 to GND?

Comment: Is this a differentiator? It doesn't look like one to me.

Comment: How repeatable is the 2 minutes' time? Two minutes after when? (Are you turning multiple boards on at the same time? Can you switch power to just this block on and off and see if it is good for 2 minutes, or if the time is based on something else going on in your system?). Are there any potential sources of electrical noise or mechanical vibration nearby?

Comment: This is the most repeatable issue I've seen across two different boards, but it doesn't happen every time. It seems like once the noise is begins showing, once I power it on later, the noise will continue. If I power the board on, all components turn on. There's no mechanical noise around, but what kinds of electrical noise are you referring to?

Comment: @DKNguyen More on this circuit here. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/432697/bipolar-signal-used-in-differential-adc

Comment: Connor. Supply Bypass never goes to the outputs to gnd. It means across supply to gnd near IC.   Something fundamentally wrong with understanding of common mode and differential mode for signals and noise

Comment: You need a capacitor between pin 7 and ground.

Comment: Sorry, I think I needed to be more specific with my question. This circuit does in fact work on a breadboard, and I have another differentiator on my pcb that does work as expected. I'm asking more specifically if something like the orientation of the traces is affecting this specific setup. Two boards have the same issue with the same differential circuit where there second one works fine.